# How do I fix this error in Android Studio if I have already added the Google Maven repository?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I'm using Android Studio version 2.3.3 and Facing the Gradle Error. I have Added the `Logcat` Error Below..

I've tried several the solution on Stack Overflow which says add the Google Maven repository, but the error already persists. I'm adding the code below too:

Already added Maven repository by Google. Still does NOT work.

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/Haris Usmani/AndroidStudioProjects/CabApp/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I expect `gradle` to build successfully but it does not do that. Instead it fails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.x.x` doesn't exist.

You can check the [revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions).

[Also:](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

> Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

Comment: So if com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.x.x does not exist, how do I fix it, or upgrade to version 28.0.0?

Comment: @HarisUsmani The 28.0.0 is the last release of the support library. You can use it, otherwise as described in the answer you have to migrate to the new androidx libraries. keep in mind that the latest version of firebase and google play services libraries require androidx support (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019)

Comment: Okay, but how? Like am I supposed to add some bit of code or something? Sorry If I sound dumb, I'm very new to Android Studio haha.

Comment: Here all the info to migrate: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate